# How do I save result of a join to another table?

Tags: postgresql, join

In PostgreSQL I can save result if `SELECT` to another table with [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html):

```
SELECT id INTO new_record_ids FROM new_table
  EXCEPT
    SELECT id FROM old_table
ORDER BY id;
```

However this doesn't work for for joins:

```
-- doesn't work:
SELECT * INTO new_records FROM new_table
  JOIN new_record_ids ON new_record_ids.id = new_table.id
ORDER BY new_table.id;
```

The join itself is correct:

```
-- works:
SELECT * FROM new_table
  JOIN new_record_ids ON new_record_ids.id = new_table.id
ORDER BY new_table.id;
```

My question is: how to save joint table to another table?

Comment: `SELECT new_table.* INTO ...` ? Or select the columns you want their values to be inserted in the `new_records` table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: both your solutions work. Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: `create table .. as select ..` is preferred over the non-standard `select .. into` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to insert rows to a table that already exists, in which case you'll need something like...

```
INSERT INTO new_records
SELECT * FROM new_table t JOIN new_record_ids r ON(r.id = t.id)
--this assumes the result of the select has the same column layout as new_records...
--which seems unlikely. replace (SELECT *...) with (SELECT column1, column2, etc...) to match the new_records column layout
ORDER BY t.id
--assuming you meant new_table.id instead of new.id although the ORDER BY clause seems extraneous for an insert anyway
```

If I misinterpreted and you're trying to select into a new table that has not yet been created, check the docs for [CREATE TABLE...AS SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtableas.html) syntax.

EDIT:

From the comments under your question it sounds like you're trying to populate a brand new table with the query results, in which case...

```
CREATE TABLE new_records AS
SELECT t.* FROM new_table t JOIN new_record_ids r ON(r.id = t.id);
```

...should work just fine. As pointed out in comments, the [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html) docs state:

> The PostgreSQL usage of SELECT INTO to represent table creation is
>   historical. It is best to use CREATE TABLE AS for this purpose in new
>   code.