# Saving output from INNER JOIN into a new table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, export

So I have a query in MySQL with an `INNER JOIN` which goes as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `distributors` INNER JOIN `manufacturers` WHERE distributors.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.manufacturer_id
```

How do I go about exporting the results from this table into an entirely new table? maybe something like:

`CREATE TABLE manufacturer_distributor_results FROM my_join_results`?

**Note: This is not a duplicate of [How do I save result of a join to another table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/how-do-i-save-result-of-a-join-to-another-table) as that question is specifically for PostgreSQL and the code does not seem to work for me in MySQL.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in MySQL is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

You're probably familiar with syntax like `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (...)`.

You can also write `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...`. That is, no `VALUES` clause listing tuples, but any `SELECT` query can be used instead, provided the `SELECT` has the same number and type of columns matching those to insert into.

You can use a JOIN or any other type of `SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO manufacturer_distributor_results
SELECT * FROM `distributors` INNER JOIN `manufacturers` 
  ON distributors.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.manufacturer_id;
```

The `INSERT...SELECT` syntax requires that you create the table first.

There is also syntax to create a new table directly from the result of a `SELECT` query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer_distributor_results
SELECT * FROM `distributors` INNER JOIN `manufacturers` 
  ON distributors.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.manufacturer_id;
```

Optionally you may define the columns so you can specify names, data types, indexes, etc. Otherwise it will infer the names and types from the query result of your `SELECT`. Read the manual for more details and examples.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thank you for the answer. So It's already a feature of `SELECT` which of course, as you said, can be used with any `JOIN` as well. I was thinking that there would be some complex query for this I would have to write but this turned out to be fairly simple.

Comment: Just pointing out for future viewers, this does give a duplicate column name error due to the fact that `distributors.manufacturer_id` and `manufacturers.manufacturer_id` both have the same column name for the `manufacturer_id` in *my* database structure which I fixed simply by renaming the `manufacturer_id` in `distributors` to `distributor_manufacter_id`. So if you have a similar case, you can again, just rename the appropriate columns.

Comment: You don't even really have to do that. If you define the columns like `INSERT INTO <table> (...columns...)` or `CREATE TABLE <name> (...column definitions...)` then it doesn't care that the `SELECT` result set has duplicate column names. It just maps the columns of the result into the destination columns by position, not by name.